# Suppress child node from being informed about an event without consuming the same one

Tags: user-interface, javafx, event-handling

#### Situation

Let's say you have a `Scene` which contains a single complex control that itself contains a `TextArea`. The complex control is composed in a way, that when it gains the focus the `TextArea` gains the focus.

The ComplexControl has the ability to make the TextArea non-editable. Then a key input can has another semantic than operating a text. The new semantic can be defined by the ComplexControl or any node soemwhat higher in the scene graph.

The Scene has a global shortcut CTRL+N for opening a new Tab/View. In context of the ComplexControl CRTL+N semantic is creating a new Text document.

```
------------------------
| Scene                |
|  ------------------  |
|  | ComplexControl |  |
|  |  ------------  |  |
|  |  | TextArea |  |  |
|  |  ------------  |  |
|  ------------------  |
------------------------
```

#### Objective

React globally or by a node somewhat higher in the scene graph on KeyEvents / KeyCombinations. Any control somewhat lower can take over the events, so that in a more special context an occurred event has more relevance as globally defined.

#### Suggestion

Setting a `KeyHandler` onto the `Scene` or a higher `Node`. Any `EventHandler` closer to the Source/Target of the `EventDispatchChain`" can consume the event. This way the `KeyHandler` can prevent the `Scene` or any higher `Node` from reacting on the key input, which is what the user intends in the special context of a control. Therefore an `EventFilter` at the higher place is not suitable.

#### Trouble

The `TextArea` consumes always any key event, even if it's not the intention of the design. No `EventHandler` higher in the `EventDispatchChain` gets informed.

#### Problem

1. How can it be forced to give the event back from the `TextArea` without consuming it and then let it bubble up the `EventDispatchChain`?
2. How can delivering the Event down to the TextArea be prevented without consuming it, so that it not even knows anything about the event.

Comment: One way I can think of is having a filter in `ComplexControl` (or the direct parent of the `TextArea`) that tests whether the *target* is the `TextArea` and the `TextArea` should not currently accept keystrokes (or this specific `KeyEvent`) - in which case you would *consume* this event and *refire* it, only this time with the target being the direct parent of the `TextArea` (or the `ComplexControl`). This way the `TextArea` has no knowledge of the event, but handling is processed bottom-up, so nodes closer to the original target (the `TextArea`) have a chance to handle and consume it.

Comment: That simple... Many thanks. That answers question No. 2

Answer (score 1):

Thanx to sillyfly, who showed me the way. As an answer to question 2, here's the resulting source. I decided to place the functionality at a central point for reuse and give the opportunity to make the suppression condition based. Please don't blame me for the class name, that's not the point ;-)

```
public class EventUtil {

  /**
   * Prevents Events of the given <b>eventTypes</b> to be passed down during the
   * event capturing phase, if the <b>condition</b> is met.
   * 
   * @param node
   *          The Node, whose descendants should not be informed about the Event
   * @param eventTypes
   *          The types of Events for which the prevention should be valid
   * @param condition
   *          The condition that must be met to prevent passing the Event down
   */
  public static void preventPassDown(Node node, Supplier<Boolean> condition, EventType<?>... eventTypes) {
    for (EventType<?> eventType : eventTypes) {
      if (eventTypes == null) {
        return;
      }
      node.addEventFilter(eventType, event -> {
        if (condition.get()) {
          event.consume();
          Parent parent = node.getParent();
          if (parent != null) {
            Event.fireEvent(parent, event);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }

  /**
   * Prevents Events of the given <b>eventTypes</b> to be passed down during the
   * event capturing phase.
   * 
   * @param node
   *          The Node, whose descendants should not be informed about the Event
   * @param eventTypes
   *          The types of Events for which the prevention should be valid
   */
  public static void preventPassDown(Node node, EventType<?>... eventTypes) {
    preventPassDown(node, () -> true, eventTypes);
  }
```

If someone finds an answer to question 1, please feel free to jump in.